# Order Preserving Merge Executor/Operator in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I want to merge multiple streams using Spark. All of the streams are themselves ordered.
I want result to be ordered also after merge (coalesce) operation.

As an example, following streams

```
[1,2,2,4,6,7,9,..], [3,4,4,8,10,..]
```

should produce stream below

```
[1,2,2,3,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,10,..]
```

after merge.

Is there an executor/operator for this task.